# Proving Composition of Uniformly Continuous/Convergent Function Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm not very good at this analysis stuff, it turns out. Introduction to Analysis went great, but this intermediate real analysis thing is kicking me in the rear.

So, the problem: $f_{n}: D \rightarrow [c,d]$ converges uniformly to $F: D \rightarrow [c,d].$ The function $g$ is continuous on $[c,d].$ Prove that $g(f_{n})$ converges uniformly to $g(F)$ on $D$.

Hint: Start with the continuity of $g$.

I have no idea where to start with this problem. I feel like I'm missing an important fact to get started, and though there are similar problems on this site, I've not found one close enough to help :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $g$ is continuous on $[c,d]$, it is uniformly continuous on $[c,d]$. Hence, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $a,b\in [c,d]$, $|a - b| < \delta$ implies $|g(a) - g(b)| < \varepsilon$. Since $f_n \to F$ uniformly on $D$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, $|f_n(x) - F(x)| < \delta$ for all $x\in D$. So if $n \ge N$ and $x \in D$, $|f_n(x) - F(x)| < \delta$, which implies $|g(f_n(x)) - g(F(x))| < \varepsilon$. Hence $g(f_n) \to g(F)$ uniformly on $D$.

Comment: Hm... I suppose this is doable because epsilon is arbitrary in both cases, so as long as fn(x) and F(x) are in [c,d] (which we know to be the case), we can say that it's the same epsilon between the two and then we're done?

Comment: I used the same $\varepsilon$ throughout. But since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the last statement can be made.

Comment: Should that first delta be an epsilon? Edit: don't think it should, I understand! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Begin with the fact that $g$ is continuous on the compact set $[c,d]$, so it is uniformly continuos there.   Can you carry this further?

Comment: Nope. I've written that out, and its definition, and then the definition for fn -> F, but I'm very uncertain how to combine them. The other answer seems to explain, but it feels like cheating and I can't pinpoint how I'd do it myself.